# How to concatenate method request parameters in body mapping template AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to retrieve a list of entries from AWS DynamoDB with a primary hash and sort key composite.

The idea is to retrieve a list which matches a given query string value which is a part of the sort key, for example, the sort keys can be  **a_b_c**, **a_d_e**, **a_f_g** and i need to get the all entries with **b** in it.

I am asking for three query strings from the client and concatenating them in the body mapping template in the **integration request** section of AWS API gateway.

I am searching the web to accomplish the same but haven't been successful in finding a solution.

It would save a lot of time if somebody could help me with this.

Below is my approach.

```
{
    "TableName": "$util.escapeJavaScript("$context.stage\_TableName").replaceAll("\\","")",
    "FilterExpression": "identityId = :v1 and aWithbWithc = :v2 + _ + :v3 + _ + :v4",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId"
        },
        ":v2" : {
            "S" : "$input.params('a')"
        },
        ":v3" : {
            "S" : "$input.params('b')"
        },
        ":v4" : {
            "S" : "$input.params('c')"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and putting it out here.

```
{
    "TableName": "$util.escapeJavaScript("$context.stage\_TableName").replaceAll("\\","")",
    "FilterExpression": "identityId = :v1 and aWithbWithc = :v2",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId"
        },
        ":v2" : {
            "S" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params('a'))__$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params('b'))__$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params('c'))"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like

```
{
#set($tableNameSuffix = "_TableName")
"TableName": "$stageVariables.environment$tableNameSuffix",
"ConsistentRead": true,
"KeyConditionExpression": "XXX = :val",
"ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":val": {
        "S": "$method.request.path.xxx"
        }
    }
}
```